# How to make sure that the number of PlotPoints is sufficient for giving the complete result? (How to have a plot of the whole solutions?))

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy

I want to see the domain in which function $f$ is positive. I use this code

```
f := (7 + 10 x^2 - x^4 + (3 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 x]) Sin[ x]^2 ;
Plot[If[f > 0, 0], {x, 0, 1000}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Directive[Thickness[.01], Red]}, 
 PlotPoints -> 5000, WorkingPrecision -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 6]
```

[image]

but when I increase the value of PlotPoints, I see that the red parts are increasing continuously. How can I know the maximum value of PlotPoints which gives me the whole result (all the positive part)? Especially when I need to see data for a very large number of x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f := (7 + 10 x^2 - x^4 + (3 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 x]) Sin[x]^2;
```

The domain is

```
dom = Reduce[{f > 0, 0 <= x <= 1000}, x];
```

Looking at the first few intervals in the domain

```
dom[[1 ;; 5]]
```

[image]

The number of intervals is

```
Length@dom

(* 637 *)
```

Use [`NumberLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberLinePlot.html)

```
NumberLinePlot[dom, x]
```

[image]

This is too dense to be meaningful. Looking at a small region

```
NumberLinePlot[dom, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So, this command   ```NumberLinePlot[dom, x] ```  gives the whole results, right?

Comment: Yes. `dom` is the whole result and the plot displays `dom`

Comment: Thanks. But I get this error for dom command: "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. >>"

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: this version 10.4

Comment: I do not have that version. Try looking at a smaller interval, e.g., `xmin = 0; dom = 
 Reduce[{f > 0, xmin <= x <= xmin + 20}, x]; NumberLinePlot[dom, {x, 
  xmin, xmin + 20}]` You could also use `Manipulate` to control `xmin`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we should split the the domain of definition into several intervals.

```
domMax = 100;
sols = Reduce[(7 + 10 x^2 - x^4 + (3 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 x]) Sin[x]^2 > 0 &&
      0 <= x <= domMax, x, Reals] // N;
Table[Plot[{(7 + 10 x^2 - x^4 + (3 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 x]) Sin[x]^2, 0}, 
  x ∈ ImplicitRegion[sols[[i]], x], PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red},
   TicksStyle -> Directive["Label", Tiny]], {i, Length@sols}]
```

[image]

**Explain the above codes.**

we use `Reduce` to find all the interval which the function is positive. For example, the first interval is `0. < x < 1.38363`,the second interval is `2.0214 < x < 3.14159` etc.

An then we can `Plot` function by using the  `x ∈ ImplicitRegion` to set the range of function.

```
Plot[(7 + 10 x^2 - x^4 + (3 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 x]) Sin[x]^2, 
 x ∈ ImplicitRegion[0. < x < 1.38363, x]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain more?